# MySQL only one active record, multiple inactive records

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

I've got this MySQL-table:

```
id | staffId | companyId | active | somevalue
```

When I create an UNIQUE index on `staffId`, `companyId` and `active` I can store a maximum of two records. One with active `1` and one with active `0`.

I would like to make sure I can have only one active record while it is possible to have multiple inactive records. For example:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1

1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 5

1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 7
```

Should be possible, but adding this record should cause an error:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 9
```

Comment: You'll have to enforce that restriction within your queries, not by using table constraints.

Comment: As MySQL doesn't support conditional indexes, you could check and validate this yourself using triggers. [This](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-to-create-a-conditional-index-on-mysql) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing NULL instead of 0 for an incactive record seems to work :-) I wonder if there are better solutions?